# Unwanted form submission with IE8, .submit() error

Tags: jquery, forms, jsp, internet-explorer-8

Well, just another IE8 problem, i couldn't figure it out, looked through other's questions and searched through the net.

So, my problem goes:

```
$('#searchFormPart').submit(function () {
    if ($('#mainSearchField').val().length == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

I have a form in a jsp page, and this code block here is for the form and is in the same jsp page. But the problem is there are other forms as well in the "*parent*" page where this "*jsp page*" is included. 
And the problem is when i submit those other forms the "#searchFormPart" is submitted first  and if the condition is false, the other submits too don't work.
The problems is specific to IE8 only, not even IE9.Hope for help!!

The Form goes like this

```
<form id="searchFormPart" class="search-form" method="get" action="search.jsp"> 
<input id="mainSearchField" class="main-search-feild" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Qology Site" value="<%if (queryPlace.trim().equals("")) {%><%} else {%><%=queryPlace%><%}%>">
<!--<input type="submit" id="recent-searches" class="search-filter btn-rect">-->
<div id="recent-searches" class="search-filter btn-rect">
<div class="label">RECENT SEARCHES  <span class="unicode-arrow">&#9660;<span></div>
<ul class="recent-searches-results-holder">
             <%
                          for (int i = 0; i < kws1.size(); i++) {
                          Searches searches = kws1.get(i);
                          String kw = searches.getKw();
                          //  String kw = kws1.get(i);
              %> 
 <li class="recent-searches-result"><p><a href="search.jsp?q=<%=kw%>"><%=kw%></a></p></li> 
               <%}%> 
                </ul>
            </div>
<input id="searchSubBtn" type="submit" value="" class="icon-search search-input-button" />
      </form>
```

One of those other forms in parent page,

```
<form action="qa.jsp" method="POST" class="qPosed">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="size_q_posed" value="<%=start_q_posed - 3%>"></input>
                                    <input class="btn-rect_more" style="margin-left: 5px;" type="submit"  value="less"></input>   
                                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#searchFormPart').submit(function() {
     var fVal = $('#mainSearchField').val();
     if (fVal != undefined && fVal.length != 0)
         {
              return true;
         }
     return false;             
});
```